# How to use jquery in cakePHP

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I am very new to cakePHP. Please explain me in steps to use jQuery in my view. And also explain me any simple example.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/6925511/287948

Comment: Cmon more data and answers. @Vinay you would have already learnt a lot by now. Share some insight!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try google for tutorials & more there are plenty of cakephp rekated jquery tutorials on there.

Here are some useful links you can take a look at:

[http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2009/01/19/jquery-in-the-cakephp-world-part-1](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2009/01/19/jquery-in-the-cakephp-world-part-1/)

[http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2009/01/21/jquery-in-the-cakephp-world-part-2-is-client-side-code-all-that-great/](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2009/01/21/jquery-in-the-cakephp-world-part-2-is-client-side-code-all-that-great//)

http://www.cakephp.bee.pl/download

Comment: Thanks for the giving the reference links

Comment: very old, there are new one? 2013, CakePHP2.