# CakePHP and JQuery Integration

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I am trying to get CakePHP working with JQuery.
Below is the div that I have in place, and all I am trying to do is simply alert("CLICKED!"); whenever the below link is clicked.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Link Click Me', '#', array('onclick'=>'return false;', 'id'=>'divId', 'class'=>'divClass')); ?>
```

I have the following files 'jquery-1.5.2.js' and 'js_file.js' in the 'js' directory of the 'webroot' folder in my project, and JQuery is working, but I cant seem to get this particular functionality working.

Any suggestions??

Code for jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.divClass').click( function(){
        alert("TESTING!");
    });

});
```

And this is the view:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Link Click Me', '#', array(  'id'=>'divId', 'class'=>'divClass')); ?>
```

I am still looking for an answer to this question guys....

Comment: Did you try removing the `onclick="return false;"` from the link? It might interfere with the jQuery click event.

Comment: Hi, yes ive removed the code mentioned above, but there is no difference. I cant seem to target any elements (div,span,links etc) from within cakephp. Do you have any other ideas??

Comment: You say "jQuery is working" -- how can you tell if you can't target any elements?

Comment: Also look at the generated html and make sure that the Html helper has actually added the ids and classes to the elements.

Comment: Because on document.ready() i have an alert() which pops up each time I refresh the page. Targetting elements, however, doesnt seem to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post your jQuery code for the alert.

You may need to use bind() instead of click().

Remove *onclick="return false;"* from the link and add *return false;* to the end of the jQuery click function.

Comment: I might suggest using `preventDefault()` rather than return false (http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/), but the placement in the event handler is definitely the way to go.

Comment: I hadn't heard of that! Nice one :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the fact that I didnt include these at the top of the view:

```
<!-- IMPORTS: -->
<?php $this->Html->css("css_file", null, array("inline"=>false)); ?>
<?php echo $html->script("jquery-1.5.2"); ?>
<?php echo $html->script("js_file"); ?>
```

Comment: Use `$this->Html->script()`, don't mix and match. Also, did you see the JS helper in CakePHP? http://book.cakephp.org/view/1592/Js